# how to take input from dictionaries ? and print that desired value ..i want to use input function and print "zinger burer"

Tags: python

how to take input from dictionaries ? and print that desired value ..i want to use input function and print "zinger burer"

```
menu = {
    "burger": { 
        "zinger burger": 230,
        "zinger cheese burger": 260,
        "thames special burger": 320,
        "beef burger": 250,
        "tower burger": 320,
        "fish burger": 260,
        "fish cheese burger": 290,
        "fire stone burger": 170,
        "crispy burger": 170,
        "chicker burger": 180,
        "tikka burger": 170,
        "shami burger": 170,
    },
    "steaks": {
        "Arizon steak": 650,
        "Mushroom steak": 650,
        "Pepper steak ": 650,
        "Polo tuscany": 650,
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some tries, also example input and expected output

Comment: To be clear on what you would like to do: Do you need to perform a *reverse* lookup in the dictionary? Because finding the key for a value is a bit harder than the other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [] operator will allow you to get data from dictionaries

```
menutype = input("burger or steaks? ")
foodtype = input("what specifically? ")
print(menu[menutype][foodtype])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read between the lines, you'd like to take e.g. `s = 'zinger burger'` and return something like `230`. If so:

```
s = 'zinger burger'

sub = {k: p for _, d in menu.items() for k, p in d.items() if s.lower() in k.lower()}
sub
# out:
{'zinger burger': 230}

# and
s = 'Fish'
# out:
{'fish burger': 260, 'fish cheese burger': 290}
```

When there are multiple matches, you have some choices, including:

1. Take the result where the key is closest to your `s` input (by length, or by Levenshtein distance),
2. Take the maximum.